# How retrieve by c# page html generated with AngularJS

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, webrequest

I need retrieve the HTML code for a page that uses the AngularJS to process some information and generate a graph. I could easily retrieve the html code using WebRequest,  as the example below, but the content (graphic) generated by AngularJS does not come in the page code.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:36789/minhaapp#/index");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
string html = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
    html = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Because HTML, CSS and Js must be interpreted like it ware in a web browser...

Comment: I suggest that you load the data from a JSON/XML endpoint instead if possible.

Comment: Use a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`, let it load the site and then finally fetch the html from the webbrowser.

Comment: @carlos-lemos, do you find anything for this, I am also having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `Page_Load` method, call this `getHTMLContent()` method:

```
public string getHTMLContent()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
    panel.RenderControl(hw);
    String html = sb.ToString();
    return html;
}
```

The entire page is contained in an `asp:Panel` called `panel`. The way this works is from the `RenderControl()` method which you can read a little bit more about [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.rendercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx). Simply put, it gets all the content within the `asp:Panel` tags (the whole page) and once used after the `Page_Load` event has been executed, it will get all the raw HTML for the page.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called PhantomJS, which renders the js off the site first and then u can get the source after it got rendered. But obviously it will also slow down the process if you are doing a lot of websites